# How to Split the values from File

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
    }
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
    string[] readtext = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    char[] splitchar = { ' ' };
```

Here I am uploading the Input File. But it is Selecting line by line. But I need to select the value at a time..
Ex : Customer,State,Country
here I need to select Customer Value only. Not for whole line.
How can I split..???

Comment: Why are you saving your file to disk first? Does it need to be saved? You can save disk IO by reading the file from Memory directly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `SelectMany` which will flatten `IEnumerable<String[]>` (after `Split`) into `IEnumarable<String>`:

```
  protected void Button_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...

    var values =  File
      .ReadLines(path) // you don't have to read all the lines as once
      .SelectMany(line => line.Split(',')); // if values are comma separated
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.WriteAllText(path, createText)`  is what you are looking for. It's a static class which gets all the file and returns as a string variable.

Here is an example of how to use it:

[File.ReadAllText Method MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx)